# strange utf8 char behavior in blogger using javascript

Tags: javascript, utf-8, blogger

I'm using javascript in blogger but i'm having a strange behavior using the chars '¡' and '?'.
For example, the following code will show *`ñéúüëò¡!¿?`* inside the div but *`ñéúüëò&#161;!&#191;?`* as alert message.

```
<div id="test">
    </div>
    <script>
    (function () {
      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 'ñéúüëò¡!¿?';
      alert('ñéúüëò¡!¿?');
    })();
    </script>
</pre>
```

If we look at the generated code, we can see that the javascript tag has been converted to:

```
<script>
(function () {
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 'ñéúüëò&#161;!&#191;?';
alert('ñéúüëò&#161;!&#191;?');
})();
</script>
```

However, I can use an external js

```
<div id="test">
</div>
<script src="http://foo.bar/file.js"></script>
```

Being the js file (utf8 encoded):

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 'ñéúüëò¡!¿?';
alert('ñéúüëò¡!¿?');
```

An the result is the expected one: *ñéúüëò¡!¿?* inside the div and *ñéúüëò¡!¿?* as alert message.

Still more weird, I can write the following code in blogger, which leads to the wanted behavior, even if it's not too clean:

```
<div id="div1" style="display:none">¡</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none">¿</div>

<div id="test">
</div>

<script>
(function () {
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 'ñéúüëò¡!¿?';
  alert('ñéúüëò'+ document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML + '!' + document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML +'?');
})();
</script>
```

Can someone explains me how could I write proper and clean code to solve this without using external js files?

Answer (score 1):

```
'ñéúüëò¡!¿?'
```

can be written

```
'ñéúüëò\u00a1!\u00bf?'
```

which might make it past whatever over-escaping of script element bodies is happening or alternatively

```
 '\u00f1\u00e9\u00fa\u00fc\u00eb\u00f2\u00a1\u0021\u00bf\u003f'
```

which contains only 7-bit ASCII code-points, so is less likely to run into character set confusion or over-zealous escapers.

`\u00f1` encodes unicode code-point 241.  More generally `\u` followed by 4-hexadecimal digits encodes the code-point whose integer value is specified by the 4 hex digits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but.... why blogger only codifies the chars '¿' and '¡' and not the rest of non-ascii chars? Even if this would solve the problem, I think it is quite annoying writing the chars in its hexa way... try to explain your client they can't write '¡'... and they must replace it by '\u00a1'

Comment: @JorgeSainz, any answer I gave you as to why would be speculation, but I did notice that none of the letter characters require escaping, but non-ASCII punctuation do.